# What exactly does System.Diagnostics.Process UseShellExecute do?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have an MSBuild task that executes (among other things) a call to xcopy. What I have found is that this call to xcopy executes correctly when I run my MSBuild task from a batch file, and fails to execute or produce any output that would allow me any idea what is going on when that same batch file is called from another C# application with a System.Diagnostics.Process.

Both processes are launched with more or less the same structure:

```
waitProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C [executable]";
waitProc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
waitProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Furthermore by changing the "UseShellExecute" from false to true on the xcopy command I can make this succeed in both use cases, however the command fails to run in a third use case. The third use case being our automated build system which is a windows service calling msbuild directly. In the case of the failure on our build machine the copy command hangs indefinitely which is, I believe, because the System.Diagnostics.Process tries to display a window, and services do not have a Windows desktop session associated with them, so they cannot display windows.

I have tried using the "CreateNoWindow" property, and I've tried setting the "WindowStyle" to "ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden," but that does not change the behavior on the build machine.

All of this said, what I really want to know is what exactly the UseShellExecute property does, because it seems to do a whole lot more than the MSDN documentation suggests.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chris, did you ever get any further with this?  I seem to be encountering a similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085185/msbuild-buildinparallel-custom-task-spawning-process-that-fails-to-run

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) tells the Process to use the Windows Shell to execute the specified application.

Without this set, you can only execute an EXE file directly.  By setting this, you allow the Windows Shell to be used, which allows things such as specifying a .doc file and having the associated program open the file.

However, using the Windows Shell requires a valid desktop context, which is why your third use case fails.

In general, using `cmd.exe` is problematic unless you're using the Windows Shell.  You may want to just write the code to handle your "batch" operation directly - ie: use the methods from types in the [System.IO namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) to do your copying.  This would avoid this issue entirely.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it needs a valid desktop context? I kinda assumed that was the case when it was hanging on the build machine, but I really don't understand why the windows shell would need the ability to draw to the screen.

Comment: @Chris: The "windows shell" is basically explorer, and is launched when you actually login.  Unfortunately, this is a common issue with batch files on build machines - I've seen a lot of people struggle with it, and I've switched to just writing my "scripts" in C# directly to avoid the issue ;)

Comment: Also, you must specify `UseShellExecute` if you wish to modify the environment variables of the process.

Comment: Also, "Setting this property to false enables you to redirect input, output, and error streams" ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx))

Answer (score 1):

From the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx):

> Setting this property to false enables
>   you to redirect input, output, and
>   error streams.
>
> Note:    UseShellExecute must be false
>   if the UserName property is not a null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) or
>   an empty string, or an
>   InvalidOperationException will be
>   thrown when the
>   Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) method
>   is called. When you use the operating
>   system shell to start processes, you
>   can start any document (which is any
>   registered file type associated with
>   an executable that has a default open
>   action) and perform operations on the
>   file, such as printing, with the
>   Process component. When
>   UseShellExecute is false, you can
>   start only executables with the
>   Process component.
>
> Note: UseShellExecute must be true if
>   you set the ErrorDialog property to
>   true. The WorkingDirectory property
>   behaves differently when
>   UseShellExecute is true than when
>   UseShellExecute is false. When
>   UseShellExecute is true, the
>   WorkingDirectory property specifies
>   the location of the executable. If
>   WorkingDirectory is an empty string,
>   the current directory is understood to
>   contain the executable.
>
> When UseShellExecute is false, the
>   WorkingDirectory property is not used
>   to find the executable. Instead, it is
>   used by the process that is started
>   and has meaning only within the
>   context of the new process.

Answer (score 0):

The use of 'UseShellExecute' IIRC, is to allow explorer (the main shell) to execute the process and not the .NET runtime....unless somebody corrects me that I'm wrong...

Comment: this property tells operating system to execute this app by console or by shell.

Comment: @Michael - Why did you remove the signature? Surely I thought I was being polite there by saying 'best regards' instead of having none at all which is deemed rude....what's your logic? FYI - I have answered over 800 questions and not one complaint...I get a nice 'Thank you Tom' when I answered someone's question correctly or has Political Correctness gone mad! sigh

Answer (score 0):

did you specify WorkingDirectory correctly? You can see actual output of your command by adding `>c:\log.txt 2>c:\err.txt` run it wil this addition and check those files