# MSBuild BuildInParallel, custom task spawning process that fails to run

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, process

I'm using the BuildInParallel attribute of the MSBuild task to run build projects in parallel.  The root project is building four child projects.  The child projects are using a custom MSBuild task which starts a new process using System.Diagnostics.Process.  For some reason the spawned process fails to run properly when UseShellExecute is false.  I've no idea why this is and I can't figure out what the error is - all that happens is the Process.ExitCode is 1, no exception..

Here's the custom MSBuild task:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class MSBuildProcessTask : Task
{
    public string Executable { get; set; }
    public string Arguments { get; set; }

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        using (var p = new Process())
        {
            try
            {
                p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Executable, Arguments)
                                {
                                    UseShellExecute = false,
                                    //RedirectStandardOutput = true
                                };
                //p.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) =>
                //{
                //    if (e.Data != null)
                //    {
                //        Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.Normal, e.Data);
                //    }
                //};
                p.Start();
                //p.BeginOutputReadLine();
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw; // for setting breakpoint
            }
            finally
            {
                if (p.ExitCode != 0)
                {
                    Log.LogError("Error.  Exit code: " + p.ExitCode);
                }
                p.Close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here's the root MSBuild project file (Test.proj, actually I'm only building two child project here but still get the error..):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="MSBuildProcessTask" AssemblyFile="C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\bin\Debug\MSBuildProcessTask.dll" />
    <Target Name="Default">
        <ItemGroup>
            <ProjectFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Test.1.proj" />
            <ProjectFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Test.2.proj" />
            <!--<ProjectFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Test.3.proj" />
            <ProjectFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Test.4.proj" />-->
        </ItemGroup>
            <MSBuild BuildInParallel="true" Projects="@(ProjectFiles)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

And here's an example of the child project files (Test.1.proj):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="MSBuildProcessTask" AssemblyFile="C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\bin\Debug\MSBuildProcessTask.dll" />
    <Target Name="Default">
        <Message Text="Hello" />
        <MSBuildProcessTask Executable="sqlcmd" Arguments="-S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q &quot;SELECT @@VERSION&quot;" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

My command line is: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /m /nr:false C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.proj`

And here's a sample output:

```
C:\Users\Tom>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /m /nr:false C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildPr
ocessTask\Test.proj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.235]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 16/08/2011 22:22:06.
     1>Project "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
     1>Project "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.proj" (1) is building "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\reposito
       ry_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.1.proj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
     2>Default:
         Hello
     1>Project "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.proj" (1) is building "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\reposito
       ry_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.2.proj" (3) on node 2 (default targets).



------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)
        Mar 29 2009 10:11:52
        Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
        Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)


(1 rows affected)
     3>Default:
         Hello
     2>Done Building Project "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.1.proj" (default targets).
     3>C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.2.proj(6,3): error : Error.  Exit code: 1
     3>Done Building Project "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.2.proj" (default targets).
     1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.proj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.

       "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.proj" (default target) (1) ->
       "C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.2.proj" (default target) (3) ->
       (Default target) ->
         C:\Users\Tom\Sandbox\repository_trunk\MSBuildProcessTask\MSBuildProcessTask\Test.2.proj(6,3): error : Error.  Exit code: 1

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.23

C:\Users\Tom>
```

As you can see we only get output from one of the SQLCMD commands.

Comment: Nothing in any of the event logs..

Comment: (1) isn't the line  **UseShellExecute = false,** left dangling with a comma at the end? (2) when UseShellExecute is set to false, can you try the same with RedirectStandardOutput set to true?

Answer (score 0):

No chance to say what exactly causes a problem, you have to investigate it yourself or at least provide more details regarding an error.

Try out to run `MSBuild` specifying diagnostic verbosity level, it will dump very detailed output whilst run:

```
MsBuild.exe /v:diag
```

Comment: Thanks sllev, I appreciate the help.  I've spent about two days investigating myself and I'm completely stumped.  The problem is that the new process doesn't always seem to run, and doesn't produce any error message (only ExitCode 1).  /v:diag outputs more information but still no error message or clues I'm afraid.

Comment: @Tom : have you tried to debug? If you able to set break point at the constructor of MSBuildProcessTask it would be great, set break point, when enter - in VS Menu -> Debug -> Exceptions -> Enable all exceptions and then continue execution <kbd>F5</kbd> so in case of any exception you'll see it

Comment: I've tried debugging.  No exception is thrown.  The process simply finishes (with no output from SQLCMD) and ends with ExitCode 1.  Is there any way I can debug what's happening "under the hood" when I call Process.Start()..?

Comment: So it crashes on the  p.Start();  line?

Comment: Try to use procmon tool and see whether some strange file system or registry/etc activity are whilst execuring this code, also it show you Debug Output, perhaps something logged there as well

Comment: Hi @sllev, I've tried a [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) trace.  I can see that two instances of the SQLCMD process are created, but there isn't anything obvious to me that indicates why one of the spawned processes is failing to run the supplied query other than that there are fewer events captured for the process that fails.  Were you able to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving each target a unique name (not 'Default')?

I think that when you include a project, msbuild expands the included project's targets into the current project. When you add another target with the same name as an existing one, the existing one is overridden.

You can see what your expanded project looks like using the /preprocess switch as described [here](http://sedodream.com/2010/04/30/MSBuild40NewCommandLineSwitches.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Alex.  Unfortunately using a different target name doesn't make a difference - the problem still occurs.  Please note that I'm not using the [Import element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx); I'm using the [MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) to build child projects.  I don't think the MSBuild task has the behaviour you describe.